# What's the difference between asObserver, asObservable and none in RxSwift

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm new in RxSwift and Reactive programming. Here is my code:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  let dartScore = PublishSubject<Int>()
  dartScore.asObserver()
    .scan(501, accumulator: {
      intermediate, newValue in
      var result = intermediate - newValue
      return result >= 0 ? result : intermediate
    })
    .do(onNext: {
      if $0 == 0 {
        dartScore.onCompleted()
      }
    })
    .subscribe(onNext:{print($0)}, onCompleted:{print("Game over")})
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

  dartScore.onNext(13)
  dartScore.onNext(60)
  dartScore.onNext(50)
  dartScore.onNext(0)
  dartScore.onNext(0)
  dartScore.onNext(378)
```

You may notice `dartScore.asObserver()`. If I remove `.asObserver()` or replace it with `.asObservable()`, the end results are the same:

```
488
428
378
378
378
Game over
```

Can anybody help to explain what the difference is between `asObserver`, `asObservable` or nothing which is a normal `observable` object) in `Subject`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because a `Subject` is both an `ObserverType` and an `Observable`. `PublishSubject` doesn't type erase from `PublishSubject` to `AnyObserver` when you call `asObserver`, so you still have a `PublishSubject` which, since it's an `Observable`, can still be called with `subscribe`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That because PublishSubject is wrapper of Observable, then when call asObserver(), it still PublishSubject, also is Observable, and Observable can make subscribe(onNext:), let see the RxSwift document:

```
asObserver() Summary:

Returns observer interface for subject.

Declaration:

func asObserver() -> PublishSubject<Bool>
```